# How to specify a type variable that depends on a constructor argument

Tags: typescript

A class like:

```
class Extractor<T, K extends keyof T> {
    constructor(private item: T, private key: K) { }

    extract(): T[K] {
        return this.item[this.key];
    }
}
```

is unnatural to use/extend, because the type parameter K takes a string literal type.

I want the type parameters to be `<T, R>` where `R` is effectively what `T[K]` previously computed to. However, TypeScript doesn't allow `R` to refer to a constructor argument, and the type expression for the `key` parameter is not allowed to refer to the parameter itself. Also, the constructor cannot have generic type parameters.

So where can I specify the constraint that `R = T[typeof key]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, so I don't know which solution would work the best for you:

---

It is possible, using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to calculate `K` from the types `T` and your desired `R`, but it might create more headaches than it solves:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type KeyofMatching<T, R extends ValueOf<T>> = 
  ValueOf<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends R ? K : never }>;
```

The `KeyofMatching` type alias takes a type `T` and one of its property value types `R`, and returns all the keys `K` which return that type.  So `T[KeyofMatching<T, R>]` is always `R`.  Unfortunately, TypeScript is not smart enough to realize that, so if you have a value of the former type and want to return it as a value of the latter type, you have to use an assertion.  Here's a function to do that:

```
function asR<T, R extends ValueOf<T>>(x: T[KeyofMatching<T, R>]): R {
  return x as any;
}
```

Now you can define your class:

```
class Extractor<T, R extends T[keyof T]> {
  constructor(private item: T, private key: KeyofMatching<T, R>) { }
  extract(): R {
    return asR(this.item[this.key]); // note the asR()
  }
}
```

This works as as far as it goes, but when you create a new `Extractor`, the compiler will really not be able to infer the narrow value for `R` you expect:

```
const extractorNotSoGood = new Extractor({a: "you", b: true}, "b");
// inferred as Extractor<{a: string, b: boolean}, string | boolean>;
```

If you want the narrowest possible `R`, you will have to explicitly specify it:

```
const e = new Extractor<{a: string, b: boolean}, boolean>({a: "you", b: true}, "b");
```

So, that works, but has some downsides.

---

Another way to attack this is to give up on using the constructor, and instead use a static builder method.  Furthermore, since TypeScript doesn't understand that `this.item[this.key]` has type `R`, we can sidestep this by storing not a key but a function that uses the key.  Like this:

```
class Extractor<T, R extends T[keyof T]> {
  constructor(private item: T, private extractorFunction: (x: T) => R) { }
  extract(): R {
    return this.extractorFunction(this.item);
  }
  static make<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K): Extractor<T, T[K]> {
    return new Extractor(item, i => i[key]);
  }
}
```

If you use `make` instead of the constructor, you get the behavior and inference you're looking for, I think:

```
const e = Extractor.make({ a: "you", b: true }, "b");
// e is an Extractor<{a: string, b: boolean}, boolean>
```

So, this works, and avoids the problems of the earlier method, but maybe adds some problems of its own.  ‍♀️

---

Okay, hope one of those helps you make progress.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive summary of the possibilities. I had a feeling what I want is not really practical. The reason for me to want to have the type `R` as the type argument instead of `K` is that the actual `Extractor` is an abstract base class with many methods that refers to `R` and many sub-types that will need to re-state these type parameters. It will be a lot natural for my team (with a heavy Java background) to deal with a type variable that refers to a class than a string literal.